# Brownian motion and conditional probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B(t)$ be standard Brownian motion. Suppose, I want to calculate $$P(B(1)>4|B(2)=3)$$ How should I calculate this?

If the problem look like $$P(B(2)>4|B(1)=3)$$ then I know how to do that using independent increment argument, but not the above problem.

Comment: I would say to use Baye's rule: $$
\mathbb P(B(1)>4\mid B(2)=3) = \frac{\mathbb P(B(2)=3\mid B(1)>4)\mathbb P(B(1)>4)}{\mathbb P(B(2)=3)}
$$
but $\mathbb P(B(2)=3)=0$, so...

Comment: @Math1000 I was thinking about conditional distributions. Since $B(1), B(2)$ are jointly normal, I can calculate $E[B(1)|B(2)]$ and $Var[B(1)|B(2)]$, then use that to calculate the probability.Any thought on that?

Comment: I don't know that the conditional mean and variance will yield enough information to determine the conditional probability. It is worth trying to see if it yields a reasonable answer, though.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, that path is long, a simpler method would be nice.

Comment: I do not understand conditioning on events of probability zero in general though.

Comment: @Math1000 I was reading the example 5.38 given in this article https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_2_bivariate_normal_dist.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_2_bivariate_normal_dist.php we have the theorem that if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal random variables with parameters $\mu_X$, $\sigma^2_X$, $\mu_Y$, $\sigma^2_Y$, and $\rho$, then
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x] &= \mu_Y + \rho\sigma_Y\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}\\
\mathrm{Var}(Y\mid X=x) &= (1-\rho^2)\sigma^2_Y.
\end{align}
Here $X=B(1)$ and $Y=B(2)$, so $\mu_X=\mu_Y=0$, $\sigma^2_X = 1$, $\sigma^2_Y=2$, and $\rho = 1/\sqrt 2$. Hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y\mid X=3] &= (1/\sqrt 2)\sqrt 2\frac{3-0}{1} = 3\\
\mathrm{Var}(Y\mid X=3) &= (1-1/2)\cdot 2 = 1.
\end{align}
Conditioned on $\{B(2)=3\}$ we have that $B(1)$ is normally distributed with the above parameters. So we compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(B(1)>4\mid B(2)=3) &= \int_4^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12\left(x-3\right)^2}\ \mathsf dx\\ &= \frac{1}{2} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: There may be an error in my computations, but I am fairly certain this is the right approach to solving this problem. Please let me know if you find any error.

Comment: I think substitution values need to be corrected. $\mu_X=0$ and square the correlation value. The method is correct. I was hoping some of Brownian motion properties can be use here and make it simple question.

Comment: I believe the correlation value is correct:
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(B(1),B(2) = 1
$$
and
$$
\rho = \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(B(1),B(2)}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(B(1))\mathrm{Var}(B(2))}} = \frac1{\sqrt1\cdot\sqrt2} = \frac1{\sqrt 2}.
$$
Edit: Oh, I see, it is that $\rho^2$ is used in the formula for the conditional variance. I will edit my answer again.

Comment: @Math1000 It is correct, $EB_sB_t = \min\{s,t\}$ in general. We can also standardise $(B_1 \mid B_2 = 3)$ and use $\Phi$.